# Array from XML Issues using SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, arrays, api, xml-parsing, simplexml

Okay So heres the issue, using an api (lyris hq) i am being returned this xml dataset

```
<DATASET>
    <TYPE>success</TYPE>
    <RECORD>
        <DATA type="name" id="205199">Dev1</DATA>
        <DATA type="messages">4</DATA>
        <DATA type="last-sent">Jun. 26, 2012</DATA>
        <DATA type="members">1</DATA>
        <DATA type="status">active</DATA>
        <DATA type="cache-time">2012-06-26T18:21:18+00:00</DATA>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <DATA type="name" id="206378">Dev2</DATA>
        <DATA type="messages">1</DATA>
        <DATA type="last-sent"></DATA>
        <DATA type="members">2</DATA>
        <DATA type="status">active</DATA>
        <DATA type="cache-time">2012-05-31T14:47:12+00:00</DATA>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <DATA type="name" id="206379">Dev3</DATA>
        <DATA type="messages">1</DATA>
        <DATA type="last-sent"></DATA>
        <DATA type="members">1</DATA>
        <DATA type="status">active</DATA>
        <DATA type="cache-time">2012-05-31T14:47:12+00:00</DATA>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <DATA type="name" id="206380">Dev4</DATA>
        <DATA type="messages">1</DATA>
        <DATA type="last-sent"></DATA>
        <DATA type="members">1</DATA>
        <DATA type="status">active</DATA>
        <DATA type="cache-time">2012-05-31T14:47:12+00:00</DATA>
    </RECORD>
</DATASET>
```

What I'm attempting to do is create an array using SimpleXMLElement using it in this format recursively

```
$response = array(
    '{listid (id attribute from name element)}' => array(
        '{other attribute type}' => '{value}'
    ),
);
```

example of this using the dev1 (first record)

```
$response = array(
    '205199' => array(
        'name' => 'Dev1',
        'messages' => '4',
        'last-sent' => 'Jun. 26, 2012',
        'members' => '1',
        'status' => 'active',
        'cache-time' => '2012-06-26T18:21:18+00:00'
    ),
);
```

me and several members of the web team here have bashed our heads on this for a while and are getting no where so I'm hoping i can get some assistance from the hives mind so to speak lol

heres a pitiful example of what i was last attempting to use to get my result which failed obviously

```
    foreach ($responseobj->RECORD as $value) {

        $returnarray[(string)$value->DATA['id']] = array();

        foreach ($value->DATA as $k => $v) {
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($v);
            echo '</pre>';


            $returnarray[(string)$v['id']] = array((string)$v['type'] => (string)$v,);
        }
    }
```

Comment: use `->attributes()`, it is used for, you know, reading attributes ;)

Comment: I've attempted this but attributes can be accessed as array keys as i've done on the $returnarray[(string)$v['id']] = array((string)$v['type'] => (string)$v,); line.

Comment: Hm, it can nowadays? Good to know. THen it's of course just `$returnarray[(string)$value->DATA['id']][(string)$v['type']] = (string)$v;` in the loop.

Comment: Thats much closer i get this with what you've provided Array
(
    [status] => success

    [205199] => Array
        (
            [name] => Dev1
        )
    [] => Array
        (
            [messages] => 22
            [last-sent] => Sep. 23, 2011
            [members] => 41
            [status] => active
            [cache-time] => 2012-05-31T14:47:12+00:00
        )
    [206378] => Array
        (
            [name] => Dev2
        )
and so on but its not looping through and adding all the types to the array
)

Comment: No you wouldn't... Note the `(string)$value->DATA['id']`. not `$v['id']`/

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not following what your explaining.

Comment: I'll just post it as an answer then :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$x = simplexml_load_file('example.xml');
$returnarray = array();
foreach($x->RECORD as $value){
    $returnarray[(string)$value->DATA['id']] = array();
    foreach ($value->DATA as $k => $v) {
        $returnarray[(string)$value->DATA['id']][(string)$v['type']] = (string)$v;
    }
}
var_dump($returnarray);
```